# Why does this need to be malloc'd?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int * p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 10;
    *p += 10;
    printf("%d", *p);
}
```

It gives me the correct value if it is malloc'd but a bus error if I just declare it as:

```
int main(){
        int * p;
        *p = 10;
        *p += 10;
        printf("%d", *p);
    }
```

Comment: To which address is your `int * p;` pointing if you don't point it anywhere in particular ?

Comment: The *worst* thing that can happen with your second program is that `p` can happen to point to memory that you're able to read and write. In that case, you risk clobbering some important data structure. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: May be offtopic, but also free the memory at last

Answer (score 4):

An uninitialized pointer is just that; uninitialized.  Where do you expect it to point?  It's value is indeterminate and reading/writing it results in undefined behavior.

It doesn't *have to* refer to dynamically allocated memory (`malloc`), but it does have to refer to *valid* memory.  For example, this would be fine:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    int *p = &x;
    *p = 10;
    *p += 10;
    printf("%d", *p);
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I just couldn't understand why it needed to be malloc'd. So as long as the pointer is initialized (pointing to something) it won't give an error?

Comment: @Programmer24: As long as the pointer refers to valid memory, i.e., memory you are allowed to read from or write to, then reading from or writing to that memory (within its boundaries) is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{

 int *ptr; 
 //*ptr=123;   Error here....Becuase it is like trying to store 
             //some thing into a variable without creating it first.

 ptr=malloc(sizeof(int)); // what malloc does is create a integer variable for you
                          // at runtime and returns its address to ptr,
                          // Which is same as if you assingned &some_variable 
                          // to ptr if it had been already present in your program.

 return 0;
}
```